# Does a Dominated creature provoke attacks of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, conditions

If I *Dominate* a creature, can I make that creature use an at-will ranged attack that would provoke opportunity attacks? Does the creature have to use that attack even if it was smart enough to realize that the attacks it would provoke are likely to kill it, or significantly hurt it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

> ### Dominated
>
> - The creature can't take actions voluntarily. Instead, the dominator chooses a single action for the creature to take on the creature's turn: a standard, a move, a minor, or a free action. The only powers and other game features that the dominator can make the creature use are ones that can be used at will, such as at-will powers. For example, anything that is limited to being used only once per encounter or once per day does not qualify.
> - The creature grants combat advantage.
> - The creature can't flank.
>
> In spite of this condition, the creature's allies remain its allies, and its enemies remain its enemies. If the dominator tries to force the creature to throw itself into a pit or to move into some other form of hindering terrain, the creature gets a saving throw to resist entering the terrain.

<sup>Rules Compendium, Page 230</sup>

The Dominated status has two (primary) effects: the subject is effectively Dazed (except that they can't even use more than one free action), and the creature that inflicted the Dominated status on them decides which action they take. They're restricted to only selecting at-will powers, the subject's allies are still considered their allies, and they get a save if you try to walk them off a cliff (just like if you tried to do the same thing with forced movement). Otherwise, you may force them to take any action they would normally be capable of taking, no matter how much of a bad idea it is, as no other restrictions are described.

Even more effectively than forcing them to make a Ranged attack, a common tactic is to simply have them walk past multiple of your allies, or even charge one of your enemies, to provoke multiple OAs.